# Weird behavior on Power BI Service: Visual level filter automatically resets to "All" on specific page only

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

My report has several pages showing data of a survey. I have various metrics, each fetching data from different/individual tables. All have filters applied on "key" column, as it should "not be null".

Everything works fine on power bi service, except one matrix for which the key filter automatically resets to "all" instead of "not null" upon publishing to Power BI service.

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just remembering your selections? Try clicking Reset to Default to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Reset to default? How do we do that on Power BI service? I cannot see any such option on the filter pane.

Comment: If you go to the bar above a report: File, View, Edit Report, Explore, Refresh, Pin Live Page, **Reset to default**, Usage metrics, View related, Favorite, Subscribe, Share, ...