# Default filter selection issue in power BI service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

We have developed power BI report and there are couple of filters has been added, among them two of it having issue which are Year and Month filters, for those filters default values has been assigned as Current FY and Current month, but during first load of report the both filter values indicating as 'All' and once we trigger the drop down action in filter it changes to Current FY.but if we view the report through Power BI Desktop every thing works as expected.

Could someone please provide comment on this issue.

Comment: Refer to this question and comments: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939831/weird-behavior-on-power-bi-service-visual-level-filter-automatically-resets-to

Comment: Basically it seems temporary issue from PBI. now it's working as expected. please refer below PBI community discussion                                                          https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Default-filter-selection-issue-in-power-BI-service/m-p/742821#M72422